# Hidden request params and simple GET request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, request

there is an Article and Tag model.

To look for articles, associated with specific Tag, user clicks a link and follows to "/articles?tags=iPhone" URL.

In addition to "tags" param, i need to pass another param to server, say "hiddenParam", **which should not be appeared in address bar**.

So, the user should see "/articles?tags=iPhone" in address bar and additional "hiddenParam" should also be provided in request body.

Is this even possible, using standard ActionView helpers in Rails ?

Comment: personally, i don't think this is possible... it's either all show (GET), or all don't show (POST)

Answer (score 1):

You should send a POST request with the variables that you don't want to be viewable in the URL bar, but set the request path to include the parameter you do want to be viewable.

An example curl request would be:

```
curl "http://localhost:3000/articles?tags=iPhone" --data "secret=sssssh" -X POST
```

Then in your controller, both parameters should be available.

However, bear in mind that the page will not then be bookmarkable/linkable in its current state. You may really want to encrypt or hash the hidden parameter and pass it in via get if you do need the url to be available to anyone but the current user.

PS. Why don't you have a route that is /tags/:id ?

Comment: I don't have such a route, because, besides articles i have another models, that are also taggable

Comment: As an conceptual idea, it will, probably, work, but, such a request should be sent by BROWSER (not server), which does't have curl :)

Comment: Yes, I realise you want this via a browser, but curl notation to explain the request the browser would be making is easy to understand.

Comment: And in that case I'd make a bunch of routes. /articles/tagged/:slug, /products/tagged/:slug etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you really must, try this:

```
<%= form_tag('articles/?tags=iPhone', :method => "post") do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag(:hiddenParam, "mySecret") %>
  <%= submit_tag("Browse articles") %>
<% end %>
```

Then use CSS styling to make your button appear/look like a link.
Keep in mind though, that this won't work well with search engines.